# About java.util.concurrent AtomicInteger

Tags: java, unsafe, atomicinteger

I came across source code of AtomicInteger class on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java/) and found following code snippet.

```
   static {
   try {
       valueOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset
       (AtomicInteger.class.getDeclaredField("value"));
    } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Error(ex); }
}
private volatile int value;
```

How the static block know the offset of instance variable value . Static initialise when class is loaded and linked . so how can we know about the offset of the instance value at class loading time . Object are created after class loaded . Is that "value" instance variable will have fixed offset when ever object is created.
Please explain .

Answer (score 0):

`Unsafe.objectFieldOffset()` gets the offset of the declared field in the class. This is class-level information. It has nothing to do with the instance values of that field.

The offset is just used to determine which memory location to address when updating the `value` field of `AtomicInteger` instances.

Comment: To clarify, the offset is the offset into the data structure pointed to by the `this` "pointer".

Comment: The offset of the declared field in the class will be same for every instance of that class .can you elaborate more on this .

Comment: Think of the instance as a data structure. The position of the `value` field inside that data structure will be the same for every instance of that data structure. In particular, every instance is represented by a fixed reserved contiguous number of bytes. So let's say, for example, that the value of the `value` field is represented by byte 24 to 32 in that byte array. In that case, the offset is 24, and it will be like that for every instance.

Comment: Thank you for explanation :-)